# jQuery Dialog Box To Fire Once Select Option Is Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to open a dialog box once any option is selected from the dropdown list. Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$( "#dialogbox" ).dialog({ modal: true, autoOpen: false }); 
    $( "#dropdown" ).selected(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        $( "#dialogbox" ).toggle( "puff" );
    });
});
```

I think the problem is ".selected(function()" I've tried .change, .click, and none of them seem to fire the dialog box. I've been through the API documentation, but couldn't find how to do this for a dropdown. I'm new to this, and would appreciate any help.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jedimaster/qLFhj/)

Comment: You forgot to include both jQuery and jQuery UI in your fiddle. Also, what's `$("#dialogbox").dialog` supposed to target with no element with that ID?

Comment: Sorry about that. Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jedimaster/qLFhj/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#dropdown").change(function(){
    $("#dialogbox").dialog();
});
```

I suppose you have an element with #dialogbox id in your html somewhere otherwise the code won't show anything.

Comment: I swear I did this like 50 times. I was sure that was right thing. I'm so new I figured I was screwing something up. Thanks!